# I want to do basic express routing. But it return -> Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Motive: basic express routing. since there are many files in one directory, i want this directory path handled by variable. But the other file handled sparately. So when i code the path, it will require file name only. This will make easy coding off course.

Lets see i have main file app.js located on "./ " 
and here i code:

```
var next = require('./routes');
app.get('/', next.index);
```

The path is handled by variable next. I also have file index.js located on "./routes " 
and here i code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Instead of doing respond, it return error as ->

```
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

But when i replace next variable as follow from app.js:

```
var next = require('./routes/index');
app.get('/', next);
```

It work. So where do i need to change?

Comment: what do you mean where do i need to change?

Comment: I mean how to get rid of error -> Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] when i used the code in app.js (in the first code)

Comment: the first code is wrong there is no index property in routes the second is correct so i dont understand why you're trying to do the first one

Answer (score 0):

Simple..

In Node.js, when your use require, you aim to load a **module**

If you print (with `console.log`) the result of `require('./routes')` you will see that this module is not exposing `index` whatsoever

When you use `require('./routes/index')` **you are loading a different module** which contains the functionality you need

Comment: yeah he has the correct implementation at the bottom im just confused why hes asking how to get rid of the error when he has worked out what fixes it

Comment: I think that he is trying to understand better what he is doing BEFORE it goes wrong.... I admire this kind of people that ask those questions... although it has NOTHING to do with express

Comment: oh no 100% should ask these questions to better understand whats going on just confused, i believe he understands the error message as he's worked out how to resolve, i guess its just a misunderstanding on how imports work

Answer (score 0):

This code causes an error because when you use require it will automatically require the index.js file of the directory. So these 2 lines of code are the same.

```
var next = require('./routes');
var next = require('./routes/index');
```

So when you do this code it will cause an error because next.index does not exist.

```
var next = require('./routes');
app.get('/', next.index); // This will cause an error
```

The proper way to do this is:

```
var next = require('./routes');
app.get('/', next);
```